# Hubs in high-dimensional point clouds (distribution of "being within nearest neighbours of how_many other points")

Tags: statistics, euclidean-geometry, experimental-mathematics

The *hubness problem* is a phenomenon mentioned in [this paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/radovanovic10a/radovanovic10a.pdf), for instance. It claims that for random data point clouds in high-dimensional spaces, there will be "many" *hubs* -- that is, points that are within k nearest neighbors of many other points.

We define, for each point $x$, the number $N_k(x)$ to be the number of other points $y$ such that $x$ belongs to $k$ nearest members of $y$. Radonovic claims that $N_k(x)$ has approximately normal distribution for random point clouds in low dimensional manifolds, but a highly skewed distribution with long right-tail in high dimensions. Radonovic illustrates this with uniformly distributed points in $[0,1]^N$.

I tried to reproduce some of that in Python and came to a surprising observation. While the $N_k(x)$ distribution is indeed skewed in high dimensions when generating uniform point cloud in the *cube* and using the Euclidean distance function, I didn't observe this when generating uniform point clouds in the *sphere*.

Experiment with a cube (uniformly generated 2000 points in $[0,1]^{500}$)
[image]
[image]

The same experiment with a sphere (uniformly generated 2000 points in $S^{500}$)
[image]
[image]

My intuition is that there should be no difference between hub-histograms in an  $n$-cube or an $n$-sphere, because this hubeness seems to be a local phenomenon. Unless I have some stupid mistake [in the code](https://gist.github.com/franp9am/77893f90bdbfbefb956557d5c4ec6004), my intuition seems to be wrong.

Generating more points, I think I could see some skewness in the sphere as well, but only very slightly, if at all.

So here are my questions:

1. **How is the cube different from a sphere?** Could the difference be only explained by boundaries, corners or corners of corners?
2. **Any insight into this hubeness-phenomena?**